# what is lighttpd equivalent of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, zend-framework

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
```

This is Zend htaccess, I can't seem to find a lighttpd equivalent of this..

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pasting the solution we found and the url were we found it, in case we need it in the future and for the benefit of other people reading this post.

So this is a neat trick that does work on the lighttpd rewrite system.

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
    ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html)$" => "$0",
    "" => "/index.php"
)
```

http://smartycode.com/performance/zend-framework-application-lighten-the-load-server/

Comment: yet we haven't found the solution for first two lines

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: oh the following solves the problem for us, doesn't it? url.rewrite = ( "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0", "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1" ) 
courtesy of: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/05/24/clean-urls-permalinks-for-wordpress-on-lighttpd/

Comment: nope :) unfortunately it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

> yet we haven't found the solution for
>   first two lines RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

lighty has no solution for it and it seems there won't be any

review http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/985

there is a patch